# jquery slideup/down menu not sliding

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I am trying to create an accordian type menu, where two of the main nav items have 3 sub nav items each, however, the accordian seems very jumpy rather than a smooth slide motion when it changes to different links - take a look at it here, [www.rbasra.com/test](http://www.rbasra.com/test)

Sometimes there's also a white flash when some of the links are clicked.

I am using the following script on all of the pages of the site:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //avoid jumping to the top of the page when the href is an #
    $("ul.topnav > li").each(function(index) {
        if($(this).find("ul.subnav").size() != 0){
            if($(this).find("a:first-child").attr('href') == "#"){
                $(this).click(function(){return false;});
            }
        }
    });

    $("ul.topnav li").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...
        //Do nothing when the list is open
        if(!$(this).find("ul.subnav").is(':visible')){
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('5000'); 
            $(this).find("ul.subnav").slideDown('5000').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't see the problem in your webpage. Or am i clicking in the wrong place? where do I have to click?